# Operator norm of $\mathcal{A}:\ell^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $\ell^2$ denotes the sequence space, containing all sequences such that
$$\sum |x_n|^2 < \infty$$
and $\mathcal{A}$ is a (pressumingly bounded) linear operator, mapping such sequences to some real number $\in \mathbb{R}$. How would I go on defining an operator norm of such mapping? Is it even defined? I have searched through my literature and lecture notes but am unable to find something. Especially, if we have a sequence of $\mathcal{A}_n \in \ell^2$ mapping some sequence to an indexed number $r_n \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\|A\| := \sup_{x : \|x\|_{\ell^2} = 1} |Ax|$?

Comment: When you say you searched through the literature, did you search in any functional analysis textbook?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Yes, but I did look for it (my question) specifically, which was quite one-dimensional thinking from my part. It didn't occur to me to look up the definition, probably because I was unfamiliar with the concept of mapping sequences to numbers under an operator, I've never saw it before until tonight. EDIT: But in that matter, I've gained more knowledge as regards that concept, rather than just this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any linear map $T: V \to W$ between normed vector spaces, you can define
$$\|T\| := \sup_{v\in V, \|v\|_V\le 1}\|Tv\|_W.$$

Apply this with $V= \ell^2, W = \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: You can also take the supremum just over the unitary vectors
$$ \|T\| :=\sup_{\|v\| = 1} \|T v\|_W.$$

Comment: @PierreCarre That's right, but then we have to require $V\ne 0$.